# What is the difference between LVM_GETITEM and LVM_GETITEMTEXT?

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I want to get the text of a ListView row (text of the item and the subitems), but I am not sure if I should use `LVM_GETITEM` or `LVM_GETITEMTEXT`.

What is the difference between these two messages, does the first retrieve the entire information about an item or subitem while the other only retrieve the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [LVM_GETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774953.aspx) and [LVM_GETITEMTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761055.aspx) can be used to retrieve an item's or subitem's text data. Since retrieving an item's text data is a very common operation, the `LVM_GETITEMTEXT` message is provided as a convenience implementation.

To illustrate the difference, here are two implementations using either message (error handling elided for brevity):

```
std::wstring GetListViewItemText( HWND a_hWnd, int a_Item, int a_SubItem) {
    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer( 1024 );
    LVITEM lvi = { 0 };
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;  // Only required when using LVM_GETITEM
    lvi.pszText = buffer.data();
    lvi.cchTextMax = static_cast<int>( buffer.size() );
    lvi.iItem = a_Item;    // Only required when using LVM_GETITEM
    lvi.iSubItem = a_SubItem;

    ::SendMessage( hwnd, LVM_GETITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &lvi ) );

    return std::wstring( lvi.pszText );
}
```

Slightly shorter, using `LVM_GETITEMTEXT`:

```
std::wstring GetListViewItemText( HWND a_hWnd, int a_Item, int a_SubItem) {
    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer( 1024 );
    LVITEM lvi = { 0 };
    lvi.pszText = buffer.data();
    lvi.cchTextMax = static_cast<int>( buffer.size() );
    lvi.iSubItem = a_SubItem;

    ::SendMessage( hwnd, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, a_Item, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &lvi ) );

    return std::wstring( lvi.pszText );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `LVM_GETITEMTEXT` you get an extra information: the string's length.
This is an advantage for performance-sensitive operations on large lists.